# How to make a div always be the largest size it could be and not dynamically resize?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

@keyframes dotty {
  0%   { content: ''; }
  25%  { content: '.'; }
  50%  { content: '..'; }
  75%  { content: '...'; }
  100% { content: ''; }
}

.loading {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.loading::after {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: dotty steps(1, end) 1s infinite;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loading">Loading</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the element increases and decreases in size based on the amount of dots showing.

I want it to always be the same size.

The size I want it to be is the largest size that it can possibly be (that would be when it's filled with `Loading...` text).

I could solve this by setting the width property, but I don't know what the width is, and I don't want to hardcode a value.

Is it possible to size the element based a child which it doesn't have? The only solution I could think of is to create a `visibility: hidden` child with the `Loading...` text in it, but that seems a bit hackish. Also, that solution adds an extra line to the top of it, so it doesn't even work that well either.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `white-space: pre;` and add spaces instead of dots to have the content always the same

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

@keyframes dotty {
  0%   { content: '   '; }
  25%  { content: '.  '; }
  50%  { content: '.. '; }
  75%  { content: '...'; }
  100% { content: '   '; }
}

.loading {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 8px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 10ch;
}

.loading::after {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: dotty steps(1, end) 1s infinite;
  white-space: pre;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loading">Loading</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, it's almost perfect, but there's a bit of a problem. For some reason when I use the `Inter` font (the font the website is using), the div _very_ slightly grows during the animation. As in, it goes from a width of 81.3px to 81.6px to 82px. It doesn't seem to happen with other fonts. Is there any way to prevent this that you're aware of?

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/vwygacnf/

Comment: @RyanPeschel that font seems to give a width different for dots and space, try to change the font of only the pseudo element to a font without issue and close to the one you want

Comment: Err, actually using another font doesn't really seem to fix it either as a bunch of other fonts have the same issue.. And I don't want to download a whole separate font close to this one just for a single div.. And I'd like everything to be the same font as well.. Ah well back to the drawing board I guess

Answer (score 0):

Edited solution after comments:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

@keyframes dotty {
  0%   { content: ''; }
  25%  { content: '.'; }
  50%  { content: '..'; }
  75%  { content: '...'; }
  100% { content: ''; }
}

.loading {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 8px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 10ch;
}

.loading::after {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: dotty steps(1, end) 1s infinite;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loading">Loading</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mention in the original post that I do not want to hardcode a width.

Comment: Sorry, missed that!

Comment: Although it is a very simular solution, you could use width, but a little less "hard-coded". There are 10 characthers in "Loading..." so you could set width: 10ch; Then a least it will scale with font-size and such

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know `ch` was a unit. That's a good idea! I'll try that

Comment: Hmm, `ch` seems like a decent solution, but doesn't really work well with non-monospaced fonts I guess